# MySQL NOT LIKE with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql-like

My columns are as follows:-

- path
- title

What I want to do within my query is to select all rows where path is not like `'% node/ %'`, but there is one exception to this.

I want this row with path `'node/109'` to show.

This is what I did:-

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(path) as hits, path as link, MAX(title) as page FROM accesslog 
WHERE 
      MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = 11 
      AND path NOT LIKE '%node/%' 

GROUP BY path ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Possible?

Comment: Seems like `OR path = 'node/109'` is what you want... or perhps a simple union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then what if you change it to that specifically (with parenthesis)

```
AND ( path LIKE '%node/109%'
      OR path NOT LIKE '%node/%')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly. (I added parenthesis)

Comment: @Steve, Thanks, must have missed the end parenthesis.